# Javascript nested for-loop pattern

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an X or plus(+) pattern using javascript for-loop but fail to do it.
here is my code

```
function drawCross(){
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if (inputVal % 2 === 0) { // checks if the user's entered value is even
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";

        for (var row = 0; row < inputVal; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < inputVal; col++) {

                if (row == col + 3 ||  row == parseInt(inputVal / 1)) 
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "O";
                else
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "..";
            }
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

this is the final result I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Your update just shows what you want to happen, not what happens and what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

- Make sure your output element uses a monospace font. For instance, you could use  a `pre` element for this. Then you don't have to double the points to get something that is still imperfect.
- The input number should be odd, not even. Otherwise you don't have a center column/row.
- The formula for the second diagonal is not like you have it (division by 1 does not make much sense). Use `row == +inputVal - col - 1`

Apart from that, also try to interact less with the DOM: only update it when you have the final HTML string.

Here is the code:

```js
function drawCross(){
    var inputVal = +document.getElementById("input").value;
    var html = "";
    if (inputVal % 2 === 1) { // checks if the user's entered value is odd
        for (var row = 0; row < inputVal; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < inputVal; col++) {
                if (row == col ||  row == inputVal - col - 1) 
                    html += "O";
                else
                    html += ".";
            }
            html += "<br/>";
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

```html
Enter odd number: <input id="input">
<button onclick="drawCross()">Go</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: You should definitely put this answer on your profile hehehe